# jquery animate (several elements) queue

Tags: jquery, hover, jquery-animate

I have several elements that are animated. If you quickly go back and forth over the submenu, there is a queue and in worst case the functionality seems to get corrupt. I already tried `stop()`, `delay()`, `:animated`.

What do you recommend to make it happen :) ?

```
jQuery('.submenu').hover(
    function(){
    jQuery(this).find('.ico').delay(100).animate({
        height: 24
        }, 'fast', function() {
            jQuery(this).parents('.submenu').find('ul').animate({
                height: 'toggle'
                }, 'slow', function() {
            });
    });

},
function(){
    jQuery(this).find('ul').delay(100).animate({
        height: 'toggle'
        }, 'fast', function() {
            jQuery(this).parent().find('a.submenuItem .ico').animate({
                height: 18
                }, 'fast', function() {
                });
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<li class="submenu"><a href="" class="submenuItem">About<span class="ico">more</span></a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Corporate</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Facts</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Press</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Franchising</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sponsoring</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
```

Comment: I'd usually use stop() in a case like this. If you create a jsFiddle, I'll poke around in your code.

Comment: @maxedison http://jsfiddle.net/qGG53/10/

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the .clearQueue() method?

[clearQueue() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/clearQueue/)

Comment: Also the stop() method should achieve what you want - http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/01/quick-tip-prevent-animation-queue-buildup

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've tried jQuery(this).find('.ico').stop(true,false).animate... in all variants.. I've tried jQuery(this).find('.ico').clearQueue().animate.. I've read the documentation quickly, I'm not sure if I've use it correct. But it seems to help a bit, but sometimes it seems to get stuck and it won't open again.. I 'm not sure if I have to set it at all .animate-methods..?

Comment: I've already tried the link to learningjquery, I thought it would a great help and it is a good article but it didn't helped me with this situation..

Comment: Here is a jsfiddle with a neater implementation of what I think you are trying to achieve...but it still does not fix your problem. Can you confirm/deny if this is behaving as you expect - http://jsfiddle.net/qGG53/

Comment: Thank you for the effort. This is behaving like it should except of the queueing. But I have more elements to animate and I wonder if that is maybe the case. I've spotted jsfiddle earlier this day. It seems I can update it, I'll try to add some css to it for a better view of it of all the elements that needs to change.. I'll let you know.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/qGG53/11/ I've put your script in comment to let show what I was trying. It could be that it is some timing issue. Sometimes it stops for a moment or if I quickly leave it, it stays visible. But maybe I should try it with slide()?

Answer (score 1):

This question is never really resolved. So.. In meantime I have used some extra script as plugin and this helped. The animation is feeling much better now and it seems that it doesn't get the time to get stuck. The extra script is hoverIntent: http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html

Answer (score 0):

JQuery Debouncer does it all:

https://github.com/diaspora/jquery-debounce

You can also write your own solution based on .clearQueue() as noted above.